# Way to update specific values in Bootstrap cards

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, express, ejs

I apologize for the amateur question here, however, I am experiencing some issues with a quick demo website I am creating for a friend.

The purpose of the site is to take the total of all "credit card values", and then divide it by the total amount of "points" there are to arrive at the "points per dollar"

Once that is done, I'd like to multiply the "points per dollar" by the total amount of "points" that are specified in the dropdown menu by the user, and then update all of the cards that have something selected to be the proper math with their point values.

I've successfully done all the math and created functions, but I am unsure how to actually apply it to the specific cards that need it.

I've created functions to do the math, and update the header numbers, just not apply it to the respective cards.

[My code can be found here](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/papibanisu.xml)

My website is running on an express.js server with e.js as the templating engine, with bootstrap and jquery.

Any suggestions/help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code you are working on, the link is empty!

Comment: @AwatITWork Sorry about that, you can find the updated code [here](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/papibanisu.xml)

Comment: can you share response object code

Comment: You can render ejs tamplate and send an object with response. In the ejs file you can loop over that object.

Comment: @Bhaskar There is no data coming from the web server. All the math is done in the browser. The commented code snippet is for something else I am working on. I need to filter all the cards by what they have selected in the dropdown. Then apply a specific value to the card heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to assign a unique id to each card so that you can write the corresponding data.

Then you can simply do something like:

```
$(`#${id} .whatever-class-name-for-points-element`).html(points);
```

It's a bit hard to tell what's going on in your code since it's not a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but assuming you're trying to write one "points" value per employee, you could add `id="<%= sm._id %>"` or similar to each employee card.

FWIW, you probably want to use the id higher up (like on the card) and then use a data attribute (e.g. `data-id="<%= sm._id %>"`) on the input.

Happy to give you further advice if you create a working, *minimal* CodePen/CodeSandbox/etc.

Comment: Basically if the points value change, it needs update all of them. So I could update specifically by the ID but that would not update all of cards. If the total amount changes the points per dollar changes, hence there needs to be an update of all cards since the amounts are based multiplication of the number of points selected in the dropdown by the point per dollar.